# How to remove the "Today's date" button from a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-input

I am trying to remove the button on the bottom of the HTML default date picker. I can't seem to find a way. The Button says: "Today"

```
<div class="form-group" id="datepicker">
    <label id="WinterStart:" for="usr">Winter:  </label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="winterStartFrom:" min="2019-11-10">
</div>
```

[image: Date-picture]

Comment: welcome. that you can't customize as thats delivered by the browser. you could implement your own calendar picker or find a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

It may be your browser delivered setting,

[image: date picker]

**Try with** [this](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker) **or** [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

This will give you a custom date pickers.